# How can I deploy my Tensorflow Deep Learning model as a web application using Flask, GitHub and Heroku

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, heroku, deployment

I have trained a Convolutional Neural Network, saved the model to a file (model.h5) and now I want to deploy it to a web site. It should be possible to upload files to the web site for the model to analyze. What would be the easiest way of deploying my model?

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way to deploy a Deep Learning model would be to make a simple Flask application and use Heroku to deploy it to a website.

First, lets take a look at what files you need and how they should be organized:

```
project
│   runtime.txt
│   requirements.txt
│   Procfile
│   main.py
│
└───assets
│       model.h5
│   
└───templates
│       base.html
│       index.html
│
└───uploaded_files
```

#### Main.py

```py
from flask import Flask, url_for, request, render_template, jsonify, flash
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__)

# Load your model here

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def submit_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        f.save('uploaded_files/'+ secure_filename(f.filename))

        # do prediction here using the uploaded file at:
        # 'uploaded_files/'+ secure_filename(f.filename)
        
        return render_template('index.html', prediction_text='The predictions are: {}'.format(result_string))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

#### HTML pages

We will use a base.html as a template for our HTML pages. This makes it easier if we want to make more pages later.

base.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}ECG app{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<div class="jumbotron" lang="en">
    <div class="container">

            <div class="text-center">
                <h1 class="display-4">Your header</h1>
                <p class="lead">something more</p>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
<form method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data" lang="en">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="text-center">
            <div class="file-field">
                <div class="btn btn-pink btn-rounded btn-sm float-left">
                    <input type="file" name="file" autocomplete="off" required placeholder="Upload your file">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-dark text-white">{{ prediction_text }}</div>
</div>

    
{% endblock %}
```

#### Run the app locally

At this point, you should have the following file and folder structure

```
project
│
│   main.py
│
└───assets
│       model.h5
│   
└───templates
│       base.html
│       index.html
│
└───uploaded_files
```

This should be enough to run your Flask application locally on your computer. Personally, I am using Anaconda to run python scripts and keep control of my environments and I recommend you to do the same. At this point, you should make a new python environment and install the necessary packages to run the Flask application in this environment.

#### Requirements.txt

Now, with your Flask application running locally and your new python environment you need to create a requirement file. This can be done easily from the command line running

```
pip freeze > requirements. txt
```

in the command line (make sure you are in the right folder and have the right environment activated).

**Make sure you install the latest version of gunicorn before running pip freeze** you will need gunicorn when deploying your application to Heroku.

#### Procfile

To be able to run the Flask application in Heroku you need a Procfile. In our case this is a very simple file that contains this simple line of code

```
web: gunicorn main:app
```

**Remember:**

- The Procfile should not have any file extension like .txt etc.
- main:app refers to the name of the python file that contains the app, which is `main.py`. And to the name of the Flask app which is `app = Flask(__name__)`

#### runtime.txt

If you need a specific python version for your Flask application you can specify this in a runtime.txt file. In our case we write this line of code in the runtime.txt:

```
python-3.7.2
```

At this point you should have all files that is needed to deploy your Flask Application to Heroku.

#### Github repository

Now, if you don't already have done so, make a Github repository for your application and commit your code to it.

#### Heroku

Go to heroku.com and sign up for an account. After signing up go to the dashboard and click "new" to make a new application.

After choosing the name of your application you will have the opportunity to link a GitHub repository to the deployment pipeline. If you choose the connect to a GitHub repository Heroku will automatically build the latest commit to the master branch of the selected repository.

[image]

Now go ahead and connect Heroku with our new Github repository.

Make a new commit to your master branch and Heroku should build your Flask application and deploy it!